# Size of abstract class

Tags: c++, sizeof, abstract

How can I find the size of an abstract class?

```
class A
{
    virtual void PureVirtualFunction() = 0;
};
```

Since this is an abstract class, I can't create objects of this class. How will I be able to find the size of the abstract class A using the 'sizeof' operator?

Comment: Why do you want the size of an abstract class when you can't create it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *can* use the `sizeof` operator:

```
int a_size = sizeof(A);
```

Comment: But you can't create any object, since this is an abstract class. What will be the parameter for sizeof()?

Comment: the name of the type -> A
the same as you use sizeof(int) etc.

Comment: @webgenius: `sizeof` also works on _types_. Marcelo used it that way.

Comment: @webgenius: You don't need to instantiate a class to know it's size. `sizeof` does not evaluate anything. You could do `sizeof(*(A*(0)))`. @Marcelo: Store the result in `size_t`. An `int` is doubly bad because a size is never going to be less than 1 (ergo never negative), so at least use an unsigned type.

Comment: Thanks GMan, Your comment really helped.

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer is that the `sizeof` operator can take either an object *or* a type:

```
sizeof (A)
```

But really, why would you want to do this?  The fact that you're asking this seems like cause for concern.

Answer (score 2):

As stated, the question doesn't really make sense -- an instance has a size, but a class really doesn't. Since you can't create an instance of an abstract class, its size is mostly a meaningless concept. You can use `sizeof(A)`, but the result doesn't mean much -- thanks to the empty base class optimization (for one obvious example), `sizeof(A)` does *not* necessarily tell you how much using `A` as a base class will contribute to the size of a derived class.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {};
class B {};
class C {};
class D {};

class Z : public A, public B, public C, public D {};

int main() { 
     std::cout << "sizeof(A) = " << sizeof(A);
     std::cout << "sizeof(Z) = " << sizeof(Z);
     return 0;
}
```

If I run this on my computer, `sizeof(A)` shows up as 1. The obvious conclusion would be that `sizeof(Z)` must be at least four -- but in reality with the compilers I have handy (VC++, g++), it shows up as three and one respectively.

Answer (score 0):

'sizeof(A)' works just fine, you don't actually need an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create object to find the sizeof the class. You can simply do `sizeof(A)`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, which suggested using the name of the class as argument of `sizeof`, you can also declare a pointer to abstract class

```
A *p = NULL;
```

and then use `*p` as argument in `sizeof`

```
size_t size = sizeof *p;
```

This is perfrctly fine, since argument of `sizeof` is not evaluated.

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know, by default size of an abstract class is equivalent to the size of int.
so on 32-bit machine size of above class is 4bytes.

Comment: Actually you are talking about the size of the pointer to an instance